# React router not rendering specified page path while I providing it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a little problem with my router in React. I have 2 components: `Main` and `Compose`.

When I go to `mysite.com/` is render only `Main` (which is good), but when I go to `mysite.com/compose` only the `Main` is render, the `Compose` is not rendered. I want both to be rendered when you are on `/compose`.

How I can fix this?

```
return (
    <>
        <LeftSidebar />
        <div className="content">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
                    <Route index element={<Main />} />
                    <Route path="compose" element={<Compose />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="*" element={ <h1>Not found (404)</h1> } />
            </Routes>
        </div>
        <RightSidebar />
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this

```
<Route path="compose" element={<Compose />} />
```

to

```
<Route path="/compose" element={<Compose />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way will fix the bug

```
return (
    <>
        <LeftSidebar />
        <div className="content">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
                <Route path="/compose" element={<Compose />} />
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="*" element={ <h1>Not found (404)</h1> } />
            </Routes>
        </div>
        <RightSidebar />
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found how can I do that. I just need to `import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';` and use `<Outline />` on the bottom of my `Main` component which will allow to render the "sub-route" (if I am on the specified location path)

```
return (
    <>
        <LeftSidebar />
        <div className="content">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
                    <Route path="compose" element={<Compose />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="*" element={ <h1>Not found (404)</h1> } />
            </Routes>
        </div>
        <RightSidebar />
    </>
);
```